# Copying and pasting datas to the selected row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code piece from my working code which copies and pastes datas from other Worksheets to one masterworkbooks mastersheet. The code below lets me copy and paste datas from column BX to column A's first empty row and does the same for column CC to column B's first empty row. However, I would like to paste the column CC to Column B's (10th) row. How can I do this?

```
 lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 With copySheet.Range("BX2:BX" & lRow)
   pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
   .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
 End With

 'Determine last row of Column B in copySheet
 lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 With copySheet.Range("CC2:CC" & lRow)
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
  .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
 End With
```

Could you show me how I can determine how many rows are seletected to be copied?

Edit: Now I would like to add an `if` condition for another column, which should say:

> if
>
> > column U in Worksheet "data" has cell value "8636" then these values
> >     should be pasted to Column H in Worksheet "KomKo"(pastesheet); to the
> >     next row as I used the code above in the "with" part.
>
> Else( If the value in Column H is not 8636) then it should paste the
>
> > value inside this column to Column G at Worksheet "KomKo"(pastesheet)
> >     with same preferences as above again

.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? cell = cells in sheets("data").columns("U")    if cell = 8636 then paste the value to first empty cell in sheets("KomKo").columns("H") else if cell <> 8636 then paste the value to first empty cell in sheets("KomKo").columns("G")

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: Please check the edited answer. Hope that is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value` to that `pasteSheet.Range("B10").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value`

************* ANSWER TO QUESTION EDIT ****************
******* Added maxR - highest last row from column H and G *******
You could do something like this to get what you need:

```
Sub check8636values()

    Dim copySheet, pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lRowU, lRowH, lRowG, maxR, i As Long

    'Dont forget to change to the correct sheet names!!!!
    Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")
    Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("KomKo")

    lRowU = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lRowU

        lRowG = pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        lRowH = pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        maxR = Application.Max(lRowG,lRowH)

        If copySheet.Cells(i, "U").Value = "8636" Then

            pasteSheet.Cells(maxR, "H").Value = copySheet.Cells(i, "U").Value
            pasteSheet.Cells(maxR, "Y").Value = copySheet.Cells(i, "T").Value

        Else

            pasteSheet.Cells(maxR, "G").Value = copySheet.Cells(i, "U").Value
            pasteSheet.Cells(maxR, "X").Value = copySheet.Cells(i, "T").Value

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your response, works just fine! could you check my edit as well?

Comment: thanks i checked now and i have the following problem. this code seperates the values "8636" to column H and rest to G as i wanted. but i need to not have a value in H and G in the same row. If a column has 8636 and the next column has another value, then this another value should be the in the next row's Column G not the current rows. What can i do for this?

Comment: Just change the `lRowH` and `lRowG` to `i`

Comment: do you mean this current code? it does not work right

Comment: Try the new code, I hope that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: i got actually one last final question, i have multiple "data" worksheets so i use your code for data, data (2), data(3) etc, so i create new variables like lRowU2; lRowU3 for the corresponding worksheets and i use your code multiple times. I want however the first data sheet to copy and paste it to row number 910, if its 8636 then it should be not on lastempty row in H but on H910 else it should be on G910. How can i do this last part ?

Comment: Just replace maxR with 910

Comment: my final question and i promise its the last:) when i copy columns from my copysheet, i want it to start copying from the row U2 , this code lets me copy from the row U1, how can i change this ?

Comment: Change `For i = 1 To lRowU` to `For i = 2 To lRowU`

Comment: there is one final thing i want to ask; i want to copy the colum T from the copy sheet and if this has in Column U of the same row the value 8636(the same thing that we did to seperate the columns) then i would like to paste the value of this in to Column Y to pasteSheet. Else i would like to paste the values of Column T( if there is any other value then 8636 in Column  U of the same row) to Column X in pasteSheet. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Basically you have all what u need in the code already. I would suggest that u get familiar wit basic vba. Anyways, I will update the code tomorrow as it is midnight here in Tokyo and I'm going to bed...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114299/discussion-between-dawid-sa-tokyo-and-yigit-tanverdi).

Answer (score 2):

since you're dealing with one-column ranges only there's no need for the `With-End With` blocks to abbreviate the `Resize` method parameters: just use `lRow` for the first one only

moreover since you're not showing if `copySheet` and `pasteSheet` are from the same workbook it's safer to reference them before `.Rows.Count`, and prevent issue deriving from their source workbook excel version

```
    'Determine last row of Column B in copySheet
    lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lRow) = copySheet.Range("BX2:BX" & lRow).Value        
    pasteSheet.Range("B10").Resize(lRow).Value = copySheet.Range("CC2:CC" & lRow).Value
```

Comment: thanks for your response, works just fine! could you check my edit as well?